# multiline processing in sed

Tags: awk, sed

could somebody point me how to get from input like that:

---

```
GOR - USD:  
Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2574 Busy  
Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4426 Morn  
Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Alex  
.  
.  
GOR - EUR:  
Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Moy  
Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2874 Jet  
Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4126 Wet   
Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4226 Pet  
Sell 26.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-1226 Peter
```

output like this:

---

```
GOR - USD: Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2574 Busy  
GOR - USD: Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4426 Morn  
GOR - USD: Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Alex  
.  
.  
GOR - EUR: Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Moy  
GOR - EUR: Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2874 Jet  
GOR - EUR: Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4126 Wet  
GOR - EUR: Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4226 Pet  
GOR - EUR: Sell 26.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-1226 Peter
```

---

GOR - USD, GOR - EUR, Sell, Buy - are variables.

Comment: Must it be `sed`? I'd be looking at perl...

Comment: I would rather do it with `awk`, is that fine?

Comment: Do not try to do this with sed. sed is for simple substitutions on single lines. All of the arcane sed language constructs to do things across multiple lines became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. People continue to use them today mostly as a brain-teaser to see if they can figure out the magical incantation to make them produce the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `sed`

```
$ sed -r '/:/{h;d}; G; s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' file
GOR - USD:   Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2574 Busy  
GOR - USD:   Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4426 Morn  
GOR - USD:   Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Alex  
GOR - USD:   .  
GOR - USD:   .  
GOR - EUR:   Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Moy  
GOR - EUR:   Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2874 Jet  
GOR - EUR:   Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4126 Wet   
GOR - EUR:   Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4226 Pet  
GOR - EUR:   Sell 26.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-1226 Peter
```

How it works:

- `/:/{h;d}`

  Any line which contains a colon is saved to the hold-space.
- `G; s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/`

  For all other lines, we append the hold space to the line and then swap the order so that what was in the hold space prints first.

For Mac OSX or other BSD systems, try:

```
sed -E -e '/:/{h;d}' -e G -e 's/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' file
```

#### Using `awk`

```
$ awk '/:/{hdr=$0;next} {print hdr,$0}' file
GOR - USD:   Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2574 Busy  
GOR - USD:   Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4426 Morn  
GOR - USD:   Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Alex  
GOR - USD:   .  
GOR - USD:   .  
GOR - EUR:   Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Moy  
GOR - EUR:   Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2874 Jet  
GOR - EUR:   Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4126 Wet   
GOR - EUR:   Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4226 Pet  
GOR - EUR:   Sell 26.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-1226 Peter
```

How it works:

- `/:/{hdr=$0;next}`

  Any line that contains a colon is saved in the variable `hdr`.  We then skip to the next line.
- `print hdr,$0`

  For all other lines, we print the header followed by the line.

Comment: thank you, John1024,                                                                          finally for Freebsd sed I use                                                                         `sed '/:/{h;d;};G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/' file`

Answer (score 2):

I know it isn't quite what you asked, but I thought I'd offer a way of doing it in Perl - which is something I really like as a way of parsing and processing text. (You can use it like `sed`, but does lots more).

We use a regular expression to 'detect' the header line and capture it, and then every *other* line we print it as a prefix.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $header;
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
     chomp $line;
     if ( $line =~ m/\w{3} - \w{3}:/ ) {
          $header = $line;
     }
     else {
         print $header . $line,"\n";
     }
}


__DATA__
GOR - USD:  
Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2574 Busy  
Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4426 Morn  
Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Alex  
GOR - EUR:  
Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Moy  
Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2874 Jet  
Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4126 Wet   
Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4226 Pet  
Sell 26.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-1226 Peter
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lines from your sample input that are just periods do not really exist but are intended to indicate subsequent lines similar to those around them:

```
$ awk 'NF>3{print hdr, $0; next} {hdr=$0}' file
GOR - USD: Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2574 Busy  
GOR - USD: Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4426 Morn  
GOR - USD: Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Alex  
GOR - EUR: Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Moy  
GOR - EUR: Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2874 Jet  
GOR - EUR: Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4126 Wet   
GOR - EUR: Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4226 Pet  
GOR - EUR: Sell 26.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-1226 Peter
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of associative arrays in `awk`:

```
awk '!/:/{a[$0]=currency} /:/{currency=$0}END{for(i in a){ print a[i],i }}' file
GOR - USD:   Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4426 Morn  
GOR - EUR:   Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2874 Jet  
GOR - EUR:   Sell 26.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-1226 Peter   
GOR - EUR:   Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4126 Wet   
GOR - EUR:   Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Moy  
GOR - USD:   Buy 24.2000 1 200 +380 (98) 578-2574 Busy  
GOR - EUR:   Sell 25.0000 20 000 +380 (99) 444-4226 Pet  
GOR - USD:   Sell 25.1000 17 500 +380 (98) 200-3003 Alex
```